PS1 command not working from github action's workflow
I a building a custom workflow
I get the below
    At line:1 char:127
+ ... h '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f .FullNa ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '-f' operator.
At line:1 char:128
+ ... | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f .FullName) ;  } | ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '.FullName' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:127
+ ... h '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f .FullNa ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:93
+ ... inue' ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-V ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:1 char:137
+ ...  ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f .FullName) ;  } |  ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:142
+ ... ach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f .FullName) ;  } | Unblo ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:144
+ ... h-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f .FullName) ;  } | Unblock ...
+                                                                 ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression

When I try to run this in a GitHub Action Workflow:
       powershell -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null"


Try placing $_ in parenthesis as below
powershell -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$VerbosePreference = 'SilentlyContinue' ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f ($_.FullName)) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null"

